# extracting data in table using REGEXP_REPLACE

Tags: regex, oracle

I already asked this question, but I am not sure why no one is answering back.
I got a partial answer, maybe because I marked it as correct answer... Not sure, but will try my luck here again.

My data looks like this:

```
reported_name
--------------

HEMA using TM-0497
TEGDMA
Blue HEMA using TM-0510
Norbloc using TM-0545
SIMAA2 using TM-0547
Tensile Strength using
Appearance using TM-0011
Haze using TM-0561
Blue HEMA using CRM-0126
t-Amyl Alcohol
Transmittance TM-0509
DK (edge corrected) TM-0534
Decanoic Acid CRM-0200
Glycol using CRM-0094
% Ketotifen Released using TM-0578_V2_RELEASE
TMPTMA using CRM-0208
% Ketotifen Released using TM-0578_V2_RE
Ca2DTPA Assay using USP_541 (3 day drying)
Water using TM-0449 OOS Analyst 1, Equip 1, set 2
Leachable Polymer using CRM-0225 Sample B
DMA using TM-0500 2333-30e
Decanoic Acid using TM-0622 - Rev # 1
Ketotifen Fumarate Assay using TM-0624_ASSAY_RC - Rev # 2
Refractive Index using TM-0589 - Day 8
Refractive Index using TM-0589 - Rev # 0 - Day 5
```

I need my output to be like:

```
    reported_name            analysis_method    revision_number
    --------------           --------------     ------------------

    HEMA using TM-0497       TM-0497            null
    TEGDMA                   null               null
    Blue HEMA using TM-0510  TM-0510            null
    Norbloc using TM-0545    TM-0545            null
    SIMAA2 using TM-0547     TM-0547            null
    Tensile Strength using   null               null
    Appearance using TM-0011 TM-0011            null
    Haze using TM-0561       TM-0561            null
    Blue HEMA using CRM-0126 CRM-0126           null
    t-Amyl Alcohol           null               null
    Transmittance TM-0509    TM-0509            null
    DK () TM-0534            TM-0534            null
    Decanoic Acid CRM-0200   null               null
    Glycol using CRM-0094    CRM-0094           null
    % Ketotifen Released 
    using TM-0578_V2_RELEASE TM-0578_V2_RELEASE null
    TMPTMA using CRM-0208    CRM-0208           null
    % Ketotifen Released 
    using TM-0578_V2_RE      TM-0578_V2_RE      null
    Ca2DTPA Assay using 
    USP_541 (3 day drying)   USP_541            null
    Water using TM-0449 
    OOS Analyst 1            TM-0449            null
    Leachable Polymer 
    using CRM-0225 Sample B  CRM-0225           null
    DMA using TM-0500 2333-  TM-0500            null
    Decanoic Acid using 
    TM-0622 - Rev # 1        TM-0622            Rev # 1
    Ketotifen Fumarate Assay
    using TM-0624_ASSAY_RC
    - Rev # 2                TM-0624_ASSAY_RC   Rev # 2
    Refractive Index using 
    TM-0589 - Day 8          TM-0589            null
    Refractive Index using 
    TM-0589 - Rev # 0 
    - Day 5                  TM-0589            Rev # 0
```

Is this possible, because I can't seem to make it work right.
I still need to find the way to extract analysis_method, when I see things like CRM-0200 in string :  'Decanoic Acid CRM-0200'

This is what I got so far:

```
select  distinct t.reported_name, 
       (case 
           when regexp_like(t.reported_name, '.* using (.*)([ ]?[-]?[ ]?Rev.*)') 
            then regexp_replace(t.reported_name, '.* using (.*)([ ]?- Rev.*)', '\1')
          when regexp_like(t.reported_name, '.* using (.*)') 
            then regexp_replace(t.reported_name, '.* using (.*)', '\1') 
          else '' end)  as analysis_method_regexp,

        (case when regexp_like(t.reported_name, '.*[ ]?[-]?[ ]?(Rev[ ]?#[ ]?[0-9]+).*') 
          then regexp_replace(t.reported_name, '.*[ ]?[-]?[ ]?(Rev[ ]?#[ ]?[0-9]+).*', '\1') 
          else '' end)  as revision_regexp
from test t;
```

Comment: Have you thought about correcting your table schema so that a simple `select *` will get you all the correct columns?

Comment: @mason my professor told me that the data will keep coming in not-formatted-written by hand and that I have to create this 'rule' that will check for good things that I have to extract

Comment: It is impossible to create a rule for such data. Are you planning to write a case statement for each new row of coming data? Is this possible? There must be some min. rule I think. I know my comment does not help but you may already created some rules with your case statements. And the rest of data probably should be converted manually.

Comment: Before you try to code something, explain the rule(s) you want to implement in English.  If you can describe the rule(s) you want to implement in English, then we can potentially assist in coding those rules.  Until you can express the rule(s) in English, you're asking for artificially intelligent code which no one will be able to provide.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I approached the problem.  First describe the search criteria for each output column:
  - 1st column is the whole line.
  - If the line has "using" in it, then the 2nd column is the string following the word "using". 
  - If the line has the string "Rev #" in it, the 3rd column is the "Rev # " plus the string following it.

Then code the rules using regular expressions for the matching rules:

```
with sel as(
  --  Test data that matches all combinations.
  select 'TEGMA' str from dual
  union
  select 'Blue HEMA using TM-0510' str from dual
  union
  select 'Decanoic Acid using TM-0622 - Rev # 1' str from dual
  union
  select '% Ketotifen Released using TM-0578_V2_RELEASE' str from dual
  union
  select 'Leachable Polymer using CRM-0225 Sample B' str from dual
  union
  select 'Ketotifen Fumarate Assay using TM-0624_ASSAY_RC - Rev # 2' str from dual
)  
SELECT str reported_name,
       CASE
         -- if line contains " using " then...
         WHEN regexp_like(str, '.* using .*') THEN
           -- use groups. 1st group is the beginning of the line, ending with
           --   "...using ".  The second group starts right after the space after
           --   "using ", and matches any number of characters that are not a 
           --   space or the end of the line. Followed by any number of any
           --   characters that we do not care about.  
           --   Return the second group only.
           regexp_replace(str, '^(.* using )([^ $]*).*', '\2') 
       END analysis_method,
       CASE
         -- if line contains " Rev # (a number)" then..
         WHEN regexp_like(str, '.* Rev # \d.*') THEN
           regexp_replace(str, '(.* )(Rev # [^ $]).*', '\2') 
       END revision_number
from sel;
```

Output:

[image]